# If $Var(X)\leq 1/2$, prove that $P(E(X)-1\leq X\leq 2E(X))\geq 1/2$.

Tags: probability-theory, means, variance

> > Let $X$ be a positive valued random variable, 
> >      such that $Var(X)\leq 1/2$ and $E(X)\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that
> >
> > $$P\big(E(X)-1\leq X\leq 2E(X)\big)\geq 1/2.$$

I was thinking of the standard tools, but both Markov, Chebyshev inequalities provide a type $\leq$ inequality.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: $X\in {{L}^{2}}?$

Comment: Since the variance and the mean are finite, X belongs to $ L^2.$

Comment: But it was mentioned E(X) belongs R

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki: Yes?

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki  $E(X^2)=V(X)+E(X)^2<+\infty$, so $X\in L^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mu=E(X)$ and $\sigma^2=Var(X)$. There are several ways to express Chebyshev's Inequality. For bounded probabilities, that involve an interval of X $\textit{not}$ centered on $\mu$:
$$
P(|X-c|\leq t)\geq 1-\frac{E[(X-c)^2]}{t^2}
$$ 
Now $|X-c|\leq t$ is the same as $-t+c<X<t+c$. If we instead had $a<X<b$, which is the asymmetric, 2-sided case, we can get back to the inequality by setting $a=-t+c$ and $b=t+c$. 
$$
P(a\leq X \leq b)=P\left(\left|X-\frac{a+b}{2}\right|\leq \frac{b-a}{2}\right)\geq 1- \frac{\sigma^2+\left(\mu-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2}
$$
For the original problem, set $a=\mu-1>0$ (because X is positive-valued) and $b=2\mu$
$$
P(\mu-1\leq X\leq2\mu)\geq 1- \frac{\sigma^2+\left(\mu-\frac{3\mu-1}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{\mu+1}{2}\right)^2}\geq 1- \frac{1/2+\left(\frac{1-\mu}{2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{1+\mu}{2}\right)^2}
$$
Now the fraction term in the last inequality is $\leq 1/2$ because we assumed $\mu>1$ without loss of generality (otherwise, if $\mu\leq 1$, then we just truncate the lower bound at zero, and it is even easier to arrive at the final inequality).

Then $P(\mu-1\leq X\leq2\mu)\geq 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Just a question for the fraction term in the last equality: indeed, if $\mu>1$ then it is $\leq 1/2$, but how can we assume that $\mu>1$?

Comment: $X$ is (strictly) positive valued, or $X>0$. If that's the case, then the quantity $a$ above cannot be less than zero. But let's say $a\leq 0$ or $\mu\leq 1$. But by positivity of $X$, $P(\mu-1\leq X\leq 2\mu)=P(0 \leq X\leq 2\mu)$. You will get the same bounded result as $\mu>1$.

Comment: Great! Thanks again!